# How to create Intellisense compatible enum on custom bindable property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

As an example, I will refer to the `Label` control from Xamarin Forms. It has a property called `FontSize` and it's of type double.

```
/// <summary>Gets the size of the font for the label.</summary>
/// <value>To be added.</value>
/// <remarks>To be added.</remarks>
[TypeConverter(typeof (FontSizeConverter))]
public double FontSize
{
  get
  {
    return (double) this.GetValue(Label.FontSizeProperty);
  }
  set
  {
    this.SetValue(Label.FontSizeProperty, (object) value);
  }
}
```

even though it should allow you only doubles somehow when you write

```
<Label FontSize=""
```

it gives you a few options to select from (see image below) but it actually accepts both, enum value and double.

[image]

I thought it's the `[TypeConverter(typeof (FontSizeConverter))]` that made this possible but when I created my own custom property with same attribute it didn't do the trick.

So what I want is to have a custom property of type double, int, string or whatever but show few predefined options from enum which will be handled by the type converter.

EDIT: My custom `TypeConverter` works fine but the problem is that:

1. It doesn't have Intellisense on XAML
2. It gives error on XAML `Invalid value for property 'FontSize': 'XXSmall'` but it still compiles and works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting that to work for FontSize is a little bit more work then just adding a TypeConverter to the main project.

Forms provides a specific DLL to the designer that builds that list so that it can show all the available named font sizes but also not throw an error

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/55937add669a422d5974fcb057c193d64f7a3a05/Xamarin.Forms.Core.Design/AttributeTableBuilder.cs#L31

And then Forms packages that DLL into the Design directory of the nuget packages for all the different targets https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/.nuspec/Xamarin.Forms.nuspec#L137

Forms also does a similar thing with Visual so that it can show those in the intellisense as well